# Oracle Database Tracing / Logging

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, oracle, gridview

I have created a web app which connects to an oracle database. I want to display the data I have requested in a gridview, but no data is showing up. I wanted to know how to set up a trace / log to find out whether I am connecting to the database correctly and if I am pulling the requested data.

I found this article: http://www.emigar.com/wiki/index.php/Oracle_client_trace

Which would seemed like it would help though I could not find the correct files it asked for like the .trc file.

Here is my code for the connection, if that could be the problem? Which I do not think it is because there are no errors and it runs, it just does not display the data in the GridView.

```
    public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Start the stopwatch
            stopWatch();


            //alter session Enable sql_trace;

            // Obtain data connection 
            string oradb = "******************************";
            OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(oradb);  // C#
            conn.Open();
            OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();

            //Command including ref cursor 
            cmd = new OracleCommand("apps.cie_install_base_data.get_serial_trx_hist", conn);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            // Both Parameters
            OracleParameter p_serial_number = new OracleParameter();
            p_serial_number.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Char;
            p_serial_number.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
            p_serial_number.Value = "******";
            cmd.Parameters.Add(p_serial_number);

            OracleParameter p_cursor = new OracleParameter();
            p_cursor.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.RefCursor;
            p_cursor.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(p_cursor);

            // Adding the adapter and Binding Data source 
            OracleDataAdapter ad = new OracleDataAdapter(cmd);
            ad.Fill(ds);
            GridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
            GridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
            GridView1.DataBind();

            p_serial_number.Dispose();
            p_cursor.Dispose();
            cmd.Dispose();
            conn.Dispose();


        }

        // Stopwatch Code
        public void stopWatch()
        {
            Stopwatch my_watch = new Stopwatch();

            my_watch.Start();
            for (int i = 1; i < 100; i++)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(1);
            }
            my_watch.Stop();

            Label2.Text = "Elapsed: {0}" + my_watch.Elapsed;
            Label3.Text = "Elapsed in milliseconds: {0}" + my_watch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
            Label4.Text = "Elapsed timer ticks: {0}" + my_watch.ElapsedTicks;

        }

    }

} // End of Class
```

If anyone could help me find a problem with my code, solution, or tutorial on Database tracing that would be great.